# Ranges not Combining Union VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, range

I have two ranges:

1. On the left, a range of Names which is one column
2. On the right, a range of Skills which is 26 columns wide (same height as Names Column)

I am trying to combine the ranges so to form a two dimensional array. Both ranges have the same number of rows. However, the two ranges do not merge properly. When I create the array, of Skill Codes at the end, it only only includes the names.

I have also tried not using the set keyword for rngEngSkills when using Union, and the opposite occurs, the Name column is not included. Any tips on how this can be fixed?

```
With wksSkills
    

    'Get last row of engineer Names on Skills Worksheet
    iLastRowSkills = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Create range of Engineer Names
    Dim rngEngineerNames As Range
    Set rngEngineerNames = .Range("B" & iHeaderRow + 1, "B" & iLastRowSkills)
    
    'Create variables for first and last skillcode columns
    iLeftMostSkill = rngLeftMostSkillCode.column
    iRightMostSkill = rngRightMostSkillCode.column
    
    'create range for All engineer skillcodes
    Dim rngEngSkills As Range
    Set rngEngSkills = .Range(.Cells(iHeaderRow + 1, iLeftMostSkill), .Cells(iLastRowSkills, iRightMostSkill))
    
    rngEngSkills.Select
    
    Debug.Print rngEngSkills.Rows.Count
    Debug.Print rngEngineerNames.Rows.Count
    
    'Set rngEngSkills to Include Names
    Set rngEngSkills = Application.Union(rngEngineerNames, rngEngSkills)
    
    Debug.Print rngEngSkills.Columns.Count
    rngEngSkills.Select
    'Set array to Include both names and Skills
    arrEngSkillCodes = rngEngSkills
```

Comment: without seeing the data it is pretty hard to spot the error. At least it looks strange that your are referencing first column A (line 3 of code) and then column B (line 6). Try using a new variable for the unioned range. Try debugging the addresses of the two ranges and look if they are really the ranges you want.

Comment: When you say "On the right, a range of Skills which is 26 columns", what does it mean? Are there any column between the 'Names' column and the first one of the 'Skills' area? If the answer is yes, `arrEngSkillCodes = rngEngSkills` will not return a continuous array as you expect. It will return the first `Area` of the discontinuous range.

Comment: Property `Range.Column` returns the number of column of the **first** column of a range, i.e. `Range("B2:Z345").Column` will return always 2. To return last column of a range, use `myRange.Columns(myRange.Columns.Count).Column`. What is the address of  `rngLeftMostSkillCode` and `rngRightMostSkillCode`?

Comment: As @FaneDuru said, It looks like you probably have discontiguous ranges in which case `Columns.Count` will only return the number of columns in the first area, and assigning the range value to an array will only get you the first area too.